# array adding function in object literal notation

Tags: javascript, object, literals

Here is the code I am using, not quite sure how to use literal notation yet, I have to pass the `currentActiveCategories` to the function somehow. Not sure if this is even the preferred way to do it, dont want to learn bad habits.

```
var primaryCare = {
    currentActiveCategories : [ "1", "2"],
    currentValue : addValues(this.currentActiveCategories)
}

function addValues(activeCategories) {
    tempTotal;
    for(int i = 0; i < activeCategories.length; i++){
        tempTotal += activeCategories[i];
    }
    return tempTotal;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to get a total of the items in the array just _once_ at the time the object is created, or do you want to later be able to say `primaryCare.currentValue()` to get a current total at any time? (Also, are the array values supposed to be numbers or strings? Currently they're strings so your function will do string concatenation so the total will be `"12"`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your object literal creates an object with two properties, `currentActiveCategories`, which is an array, and `currentValue`, which is set to the result of calling `addValues()` *at the time the object literal is evaluated.* You are trying to call the function with `this.currentActiveCategories`, which will be `undefined`, because `this` is not equal to that object at that moment.

If the idea is to have a function that can return the current total at any time you can do this:

```
var primaryCare = {
    currentActiveCategories : [ "1", "2"],
    currentValue : function () {
                      var tempTotal = "";
                      for(var i = 0; i < this.currentActiveCategories.length; i++){
                         tempTotal += this.currentActiveCategories[i];
                      }
                      return tempTotal;
                   }
}

primaryCare.currentValue(); // returns "12", i.e., "1" + "2"
```

Always declare your variables with `var` or they'll become globals - note that you can't declare an `int` in JS. You need to initialise `tempTotal` to an empty string before you start adding strings to it, or instead of `"12"` you'll get `"undefined12"`.

When you call a function as a method of an object, like `primaryCare.currentValue()` (as shown above) then within the function `this` will be set to that object.

It seems kind of odd to me to be adding the values as strings. If you want to use numbers and get a numeric total you can do this:

```
var primaryCare = {
    currentActiveCategories : [ 1, 2],   // note no quotes around the numbers
    currentValue : function () {
                      var tempTotal = 0;
                      for(var i = 0; i < this.currentActiveCategories.length; i++){
                         tempTotal += this.currentActiveCategories[i];
                      }
                      return tempTotal;
                   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you giving the `currentValue` function a name?

Comment: And the original code wouldn't have worked because `currentValue : addValues(this.currentActiveCategories)` would've referred to `window.currentActiveCategories`

Comment: @Ian - The function had a name due to copy/paste. Fixed. And I did say that `this` would not be that object, but it may or may not be `window` depending on whether all of that code is nested inside some other function.